# can't get api responce using fetch()

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, next.js

I am trying to get data using `fetch()` using browser console number of time but can't get.
for the cross browser issue I also use mode: `no-cors`  but no solution I found .
please help me out I am fully in depressed now

the code that i already tried:

```
await fetch("https://api.sandbox.bigbuy.eu/rest/catalog/productsstock.json", {
  method: "GET",
  mode: 'no-cors',
  headers: { Authorization: `Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXX` }
})
.then(response => response.json())
```

response is:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
```

Comment: Please format your code to make it readable.

Comment: you can't use both await and then for the same promise. If you remove the await it will work

Comment: @VassilisPallas — You can. It just awaits the promise returned by `then()`.

Comment: Why are you chaining a `.then` to the awaited response ?

Comment: @KunalMukherjee to grab the json and parse it of course. There's no objective reason not to mix the two.

Comment: @KevinB this can be acheived as `JSON.parse(await fetch(...))` also right

Comment: @KunalMukherjee eh, no, that wouldn't work. but there are multiple ways to accomplish it.

Comment: @KevinB why not ?

Comment: Because fetch doesn't resolve with the json string. it resolves with a response object.

Answer (score 3):

You said `mode: 'no-cors'` but you are making a cross-origin request.

You cannot read data across origins without permission from CORS.

By explicitly turning off CORS you are telling `fetch` to set the response to nothing and not raise errors for trying to read across origins without permission from CORS.

Change it to `mode: 'cors'`. Note that `api.sandbox.bigbuy.eu` will have to grant you permission to read the data.